# How to add query string to the pager(codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a link for example:

```
http://mysite.com/5 / 5 - is page number
```

and here is all ok, but what if i have a search filter activated with the pagination:

```
http://mysite.com/5?filter=something
```

so the question is: how can i add the query string to the pager links, leaving the pager links itself as uri segments, pager links are uri segments and filter is a query string, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

In the config.php file there is section of code to allow you to enable query strings.  It should look like this.

```
$config['allow_get_array']      = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger']   = 'c';
$config['function_trigger']     = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger']    = 'd'; // experimental not currently in use
```

What are these set too for you?

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to add the searched key word to a `cookie` or a `session` 
since codeigniter pagination uses url segment,

using 
`http://mysite.com/5?filter=something` will destroy the segment because CI will think that the second parameter will be the limit and this will return false since your second uri segment is `5?filter=something`

this is how i would do it

```
public function search()
{
    //config pagination
    if($this->session->usedata('search_keyword') == false)//no search has been made
    {
        if($this->input->post('search_keyword'))
        {
            $data_to_query = $this->input->post('search_keyword');
            $this->session->set_userdata('search',$data_to_query);
            // query for database when search_keyword is entered
            $this->model->get($this->session->userdata('search')); // assuming this is your query model
        }else{
            // if session search_keyword is false then no 
            // search has been made do the normal query
        }
    }else{
        // if search_keyword session is true then a search has been made
        // use the data gathered on the session as a query parameter
    }
}
```